# Custom puppet facts not executing

Tags: puppet, fact

I have a few custom facts on the puppet server in the standard location:

```
[module_dir]/lib/puppet/facter/[fact_name].rb
```

Here is an example:

```
require 'facter'
Facter.add("fact_name") do
  setcode do
      "fact_name_value"
  end
end
```

I see they are being downloaded to the expected location on the puppet client:

```
C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\var\lib\puppet\facter\[fact_name].rb
```

However when I run `facter.bat -p` on the client I don't get `fact_name => fact_name_value` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my facts were in the wrong directory on the server.

```
[module_dir]/lib/puppet/facter/[fact_name].rb
```

Should be

```
[module_dir]/lib/facter/[fact_name].rb
```